# Loader onStartLoading method is not abstract

Tags: android, loader

I just Have a question.
Why 
`protected void onStartLoading() {}` in Loader is not abstract and has empty body because without implementing it in your loader `loadInBackground()` wont be started except if you call `forceLoad()`.
I believe it should be abstract, but maybe there are any reasons why it is not.

Comment: If it was abstract... then even the Loaders which did not need `onStartLoading` would have needed to implement this... which would have increased the boilerplate... and in a way the purpose of having these hooks would have been defeated.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh But without implementing `onStartLoading` the Loader wont get started.

Comment: You are forgetting `forceLoad()`

Comment: In that case you are right.